# how to generate sprite position such as "right -300px" in compas sass?

Tags: css, compass-sass, css-sprites

how to generate sprite position such as "right -300px" in compas sass?
I found that sass can only output background-position in numbers, but sometimes I need the sprite position to be right align or bottom align, how to do it ?
pls see my code bellow:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* ------- scss ------- */
    $map_btn: sprite-map("sprite_btn/*.png");
    .btn,.btn span{
        display:inline-block;
        background-image: sprite-url($map_btn);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .go_to_cart{
        background-position: sprite-position($map_btn,go_to_cart);
        span{
            background-position: sprite-position($map_btn,go_to_cart);
        }
    }

    /* ------- output ------- */
    .btn,.btn span{
        display:inline-block;
        background-image: url('../images/btn_sprite.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .go_to_cart{
        background-position: 0 -300px;
    }
    .go_to_cart span{
        background-position: 0 -330px;
        /* ------- 
            but I want to output like this bellow:
            how to write in scss?
        ------- */
        background-position: right -330px;
    }

</style>
<a href="#" class="btn go_to_cart">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but just in case someone needs an answer.

When using sprite maps you cant (or shouldn't) align the background like that because you're basically offsetting the scope and defeating the purpose of a sprite map.

if you want to align the sprite you should position/align the container of the sprite.